Is there a way to return/find the label of a given equation?
My purpose is the following: I have a series of equations labelling as 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, and etc. However, in the middle of these equations, I would love an extra equation which is labelled as 1.1', placing it between 1.1 and 1.2 for example. I know that I can do it by \tag{1.1'}, but is there a way to return or get the label of Equation 1.1, and add the symbol ' behind it?
PS, of course other solutions serving the same demand are welcomed.
PPS, if I use \tag{\ref{eq1}'}, there will be a hyperlink directed to equation 1. Is there a way to prevent that, i.e., is there a way to turn the reference to plain text?
Here is a sample code that illustrates the idea.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{test}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
this is the equation labelled 1
\begin{equation}
    a=b \label{eq:eq1}
\end{equation}

here is the equation in between, and I need to label it as 1'.
\begin{equation*}
    b=c \tag{1'}
\end{equation*}

this is the equation labelled 2
\begin{equation}
    a=c
\end{equation}

\end{document}


Are you able to provide an example for people to play with? The details of your set up matter.

@cfr Hi, I just added one.

\tag{\theequation'}?

@cfr Can you clarify a little? so like $\tag{\ref{eq1}'}$ in my example? But it will create a hyperlink to the equation. Is there a way to prevent that or you are saying something else

\theequation displays the value of the current equation number. So \tag{\theequation'}, as proposed by cfr, should give you the expected result.

You don't want to \ref it. Just \theequation. You're fitting it between, so the number will automatically refer to the correct one.

@jlab Oh I see! Thank you very much!

@cfr Thank you!

If @cfr doesn't, maybe you could create an answer to your own question.

If it's certain that equation n' will always follow immediately after equation n, i.e., without any intervening numbered equations, you could indeed use \tag{\theequation$'$}. Note that I'd render ' ("prime") in math mode, not text mode.
In addition, you may want to execute
\DeclareMathOperator{\numer}{num}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}

in the preamble, as E_t is the (time-t conditional) expectations operator; it's conventional to use upright (aka "roman") letters for math "operators" such as \sin, \exp, \det, and \log. Also, writing \numer (for "numeraire") is easier than \operatorname{num}, isn't it?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\DeclareMathOperator' macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\numer}{num}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
\usepackage{mleftright} \mleftright % better spacing around tall delimiters
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

The formula holds for every non-dividend-paying asset. Multiplying through by
$S(t)$, we obtain
\begin{equation} \label{eq:fund_pricing_formula}
    Y(t)=S(t) \E_t^S \left[\frac{Y(T)}{S(T)}\right]
\end{equation}
It is a present value relation: the value at time $t$ of the asset is the
expectation of its value $Y(T)$ at time $T$ ``discounted'' by the (possibly
random) factor $S(t) / S(T)$.

The formula can be written as
\begin{equation*}
    Y(t)=\numer(t) \E_t^{\numer}
    \left[\frac{Y(T)}{\numer(T)}\right]
    \tag{$\theequation'$}
\end{equation*}
where now $\numer(t)$ denotes the price of the (non-dividend-paying)
numeraire asset at time $t$.

Letting $R(t)$ denote the value $\mathrm{e}^{r t}$ of the risk-free asset and
using it as the numeraire, the equation becomes
\begin{equation}
    Y(t)=\mathrm{e}^{r t} \E_t^R
    \left[\frac{Y(T)}{\mathrm{e}^{r T}}\right]
    =\exp(-r(T-t)) \E_t^R[Y(T)]
\end{equation}
which means that $Y(t)$ is the expected value of $Y(T)$ discounted at the
risk-free rate for the remaining time $T-t$, when the expectation is computed
under the risk-neutral probability measure.

\end{document}


Tags, including equation numbers are treated as text. So you should do \theequation$'$. But what if you move the equation up or down?

@egreg - I've updated the answer to use \theequation$'$.

@egreg I thought in that case the value was supposed to move because it was meant to come 'in between'?

You can use \ref. No need to make assumption on where the specially tagged equation ends up.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{test}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
this is the equation labelled 1
\begin{equation}
    a=b \label{eq:eq1}
\end{equation}

here is the equation in between, and I need to label it as 1'.
\begin{equation*}
    b=c \tag{\ref{eq:eq1}$'$}
\end{equation*}

this is the equation labelled 2
\begin{equation}
    a=c
\end{equation}

\end{document}

In order to get a prime (not an apostrophe) you need $'$.

Note. If you also load \hyperref, \ref should become \ref* in order to avoid an unwanted link.
Can we write a special command for this? Yes.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
   % with hyperref use \ref*
   \NewDocumentCommand{\repeateq}{O{$'$}m}{\tag{\ref*{#2}#1}}%
  }{% without hyperref use \ref
   \NewDocumentCommand{\repeateq}{O{$'$}m}{\tag{\ref{#2}#1}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\title{test}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
this is the equation labelled 1
\begin{equation}
    a=b \label{eq:eq1}
\end{equation}

here is the equation in between, and I need to label it as 1'.
\begin{equation*}
    b=c \repeateq{eq:eq1}
\end{equation*}

this is the equation labelled 2
\begin{equation}
    a=c
\end{equation}

Another variant of the first equation
\begin{equation}
c=a \repeateq[*]{eq:eq1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


If I uncomment the call to hyperref, the links are right.

+1 Addressing the PPS of OP: With hyperref you might want to use \ref* to avoid creating an hyperlink.

@campa Yes, I'll add the remark.

The following example illustrates what we can do with OpTeX:
\def\prevmark[#1]{\ea\prevmarkA\expanded{\cs{_lab:#1}}}
\def\prevmarkA(#1){#1} 
% \prevmark[label] expands to previously used \eqmark[label] without ().

\noindent
this is the equation labelled 1
$$
   a=b \eqmark[first]
$$
here is the equation in between, and I need to label it as 1'.
$$
  b=c \eqno (\prevmark[first]')
$$
this is the equation labelled 2
$$
  a=c \eqmark[second]
$$
Another variant of the first equation
$$
  c=a \eqno (\prevmark[first]\hbox{*})
$$

\bye


As @jlab and @cfr commented, use \tag{\theequation'} because \theequation displays the value of the current equation number.
